# ERROR al enviar variable a php y capturando arreglo de php en jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, sql-server

Estoy haciendo un auto completar con jquery, php, sqlserver. Envio un dato por al archivo **busca-cliente.php** con ajax pero no logro obtener ningún resultado de vuelta y tampoco puedo ver algún tipo de error en el navegador.

**código JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 

        $("#rutb").keyup(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#rutsf").val(value);
            });
        $("input#rutsf").rut()
          .on('rutValido', function(e, rut){
            alert("Su RUT sin DV es " + rut);
          });


          $("#rutb").change(function () {
              $("#rutb").each(function () {
                  busca = $(this).val();
                     $.ajax({
                         type:"GET",
                         url:"busca-cliente.php",
                         data:busca,
                         dataType:"html",
                         success: function(clientes){
                            alert("dato enviado");
                            ('#nombre').find('input').val(clientes.nom);
                            }
                  });

              });
          })




        });


        </script>
```

html en la misma pagina

```
<form  method="get" id="buscador">
               <label for="rutb">Buscar cliente</label>
                <input name="rutb" type="text"  id="rutb" placeholder="Rut" 
/>
                <div class="errores" id="mrutb">El rut no es valido</div>
<!--             <button type="submit"   name="btn-buscar" id="btn-  buscar">Buscar</button> -->
        </form>
```

Este formulario de debe llenar

```
<form method="post" id="ingresar" onSubmit="return Comprobar();">
<label for="nombre">Nombre</label>    
<input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" />
</form>
```

busca-cliente.php

```
    <?php
    include_once "lib/conexion.php";


    $rutbuscador=$_GET['busca'];

      if(!empty($rutbuscador)){

        $con=conectar();
         $sqls = "SELECT    * FROM clientes WHERE (RutAux = '$rutbuscador')"; 

        $query= sqlsrv_query($con,$sqls);



        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($query)){

                while($fila=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){

                    $NOM=$fila[1];
                    $RUT=$fila[3];
                    $DIR=$fila[7];
                    $FON=$fila[8];
                    $EM=$fila[9];
                 $clientes[] = array('rut' =>$RUT,'nom' => $NOM,'tel' => $FON,'dir' => $DIR,'email' => $EM);




                }
                echo '<script>alert("$clientes[]"); </script>';
                echo $clientes;
            }else{
                ?> <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">No existen clientes con el rut : <?php echo $rutbuscador; ?></div><?php
            }
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te marca? esto lo puedes ver en la pestaña *Network* del navegador

Comment: intenta `json_encode($clientes);`

Comment: intenta removiendo esto // $("#rutb").each(function () {
ya que es una peticion asincrona
y el la query sql debes usar el operador like de comparacion...

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos pero ya lo solucione
el error era el tipo de dato quedo de la siguiente forma

```
 $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:"busca-cliente.php",
             data:{busca: $("#rutb").val()},
             dataType:"json", //Cambie a json
             success: function(res){
                $('#nombre').val(res.nom);
                $('#rut').val(res.rut);
                $('#telefono').val(res.tel);
                $('#direccion').val(res.dir);
                $('#email').val(res.email);
                $('#mensaje').val(res.mensaje);
                document.getElementById("rut").focus();
            }

     });
```

busca-cliente.php

```
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($query)){
        for($f = 1; $f <=1 ;$f++){
            $fila=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
            $NOM=$fila[1];
            $RUT=$fila[3];
            $DIR=$fila[6];
            $FON=$fila[8];
            $EM=$fila[9];
            $clientes= array("rut" =>$RUT, "nom" => $NOM,"tel" => $FON,"dir" =>$DIR,"email" => $EM);

        }

        echo json_encode($clientes); //sieguiendo el consejo que me recomendaron
        }
```